# hover object in css with all images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with my code, i added css code to get a drop down menu to activate whenever you hover over one of the images. It works... except the drop down menu only appears in the top left instead of right under the image. Please help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RSS Earth Map</title>
<style>
body {
 background-image: url("https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111096/download?f=9k7y8m7if6dkcq345y53s4yp4");
}
img {
 float: left;
}
.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: black;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 padding: 12px 16px;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><div class="terrain">
<div class="dropdown">
 <img id="cDunes" data-hover-src = 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf' src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"/>
 <img id="eDunes" data-hover-src = 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf' src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"/>
 <img id="forest" data-hover-src = 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf' src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"/>
 <img id="oasis" data-hover-src = 'https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf' src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"/>
 <img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="forest" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111094/download?f=8thtza1n3c1jcjcbz8zxjm6oy"><img id="eDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111093/download?f=butw29huynzzfmr2khesrabmf"><img id="oasis" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111095/download?f=5zrg0l9f98ec2wak40fm2wkwi"><img id="cDunes" data-hover-src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717230700/download?f=4djrzz4g3ebonnu51c14r1yaf" src="https://api.edmodo.com/files/717111092/download?f=5xvdsuiuz1khl27tlrkqk9ihy">
<div class="dropdown-content">
<p> teleport </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
   function moveBase() {
   
    //Assign event for each image holding a hover-src
    for(var tL=document.querySelectorAll('img[data-hover-src]'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
     tL[i].addEventListener('click', replaceImage)
    }
   

   function resetToOriginal(){
    //Sets all images holding a original-src back to it
    for(var tL=document.querySelectorAll('img[data-original-src]'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
     var tS = tL[i].getAttribute('data-original-src');
     (tS !== tL[i].src) && (tL[i].src = tS)
    }
   }

   function replaceImage(e){
    //Clicked element
    var tE = e.srcElement || e.target;

    //Storing the original src
    !tE.getAttribute('data-original-src') && tE.setAttribute('data-original-src', tE.src);

    //Reseting all the images
    resetToOriginal()

    //Change the src
    tE.src = tE.getAttribute('data-hover-src') || tE.src
   }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar has been asked before check this out:
[Show DIV at mouse cursor on hover of span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158180/show-div-at-mouse-cursor-on-hover-of-span)

You'll wanna use javascript to display that div at the mouse cursor.

Comment: i just want it to hover down and also wanted it to be clickable with a box. Since there are so many of the images on the original is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you're doing -- you want the box to show directly below the image that was hovered over, right? You want the image to be clickable to open the box?

Comment: yes, and whenever the user clicks teleport i want the image to change to the village or (teleport) but not be able to teleport several other times after that.